# Can I play an old cd game on Linux?

Tags: networking

So I downloaded Linux since it was free, but when I put my old computer discs in my computer it for some reason thinks it's an audio disc. Am I able to tell Linux that it's actually a game? Or do I have to get an actual windows operating system to play these games?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You should specify what OS or platform were your CDs intended for. Even a photo of one of these CDs could help, this information is often printed on them.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what OS it was meant for.

If it was Windows, you will need [WINE](https://winehq.com) (which can be downloaded from the repos) and even it is not a guarantee your game will run at all.

If it was a DOS game, [Dosbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DOSBox) can run virtually every DOS game under the sun and you will find it in the repos too.

I cannot answer for Mac-based games as I have never in my life owned any Mac system.

Comment: There's a database of apps and games at https://appdb.winehq.org/ you can use to find if a game has been tested, and if so, if there are any adjustments needed to enable better running.

Comment: What about console games? They were distributed on CDs, too.

Comment: @Melebius  many console games can run on Lutris, but I'm not sure if you can install then via cd or if you have to extract files from the cd beforehand.  Here are the runners that Lutris can use to get non-native games running.  https://lutris.net/runners